How to detect if a USB flash drive was inserted on Raspberry Pi 4, and list all the files inside the USB flash drive using pyusb?
I am using Python 3.11 on Raspberry Pi 4. Say I have a USB flash drive connected on one of the USB ports of the Raspberry Pi 4. How do I get the path of the USB flash drive, so that I can list them to some UI?

normally in system (Linux or RasbianOS) you can use lsusb to list all USB devices. And as I know system may automatically mount new USB Flash Drive in folder /media (or /media/<user_name>) as subfolder. So you could check this folder to see if you have new folder. You may also try to use so called watchdog to automatically detect if there is some change in selected folder. Python should have module for watchdog

Official forum for RPi has How do detect a USB flash drive in Pi4 in Python - Raspberry Pi Forums and it seems it use /media/pi to detect new drive.

Thanks @furas, it turns out I was making things complicated where in fact there is much more simpler and faster way of solving this problem

So, based on @furas explanation. Instead of trying to access the USB ports and check if there's any device plug to it. It's better to check the /media/<user_name> if there was an additional folder that was created.
So, here's that I came up with:
def ListGCodeFiles_From_FlashDrive(self):
    dir_path = "/media/ron"
    supported_file_type = ".gcode"
    gcode_files_list = []
    
    if len(os.listdir(dir_path)) == 0:
        return gcode_files_list
    
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
            if supported_file_type in filename:
                gcode_files_list.append(file_path)
                
    return gcode_files_list

